# Hover over description JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I need some help with JavaScript, which will help me to create a hover over text description inside a `div` element if I move the mouse over some text. And this description will follow the mouse where ever I move the mouse. And after removing the mouse from the text, the hover over text will vanish. And all this needs to be done with the help of pure JavaScript and not jQuery.

Comment: how much are you paying me for this

Comment: Have you tried implementing this yourself? Edit in some code please.

Comment: How much of this have you attempted to do on your own? Please post any code you have written so far. Generally, you should have the `onmousemoved` event handler. In the handler you need to use the `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` properties to change the position of your description.

Comment: It won't follow your mouse around, but it does sound like a proper alternative - no JavaScript required at all. The HTML 'title' attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the basic principle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function moveDescrip(event)
{
    var d = document.getElementById("descrip")
    var x=event.clientX;
    var y=event.clientY;
    d.style.top = y + "px";
    d.style.left = x + "px";
}
function showDescrip(show)
{
   var d = document.getElementById("descrip");
   d.style.visibility=show ? "visible" : "hidden";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div 
    onmouseover="showDescrip(true)" 
    onmouseout="showDescrip(false)" 
    onmousemove="moveDescrip(event)" 
    style="border: 1px solid black; width: 200px; height:300px" >
    Description div will follow your mouse while you hover over.        
</div>

<div id="descrip" style="position:absolute; visibility:hidden">description</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While your answer may be perfectly good, please learn that questions asking for code that have made no attempt to implement any code themselves are off topic. By answering these particular questions you are promoting more users to post off topic questions like this.